# Console wont work

Tags: java, console

I’m using a basic `System.out.println` but it doesn’t outprint in my console.
I am using Eclipse's debug button.

What might be the issue?

```
private static void Check(){
    System.out.println("Starting");
}
```

Comment: How do you start your program? Do you use an IDE or you're just using a terminal?

Comment: Is it built as Java Application?  Are you sure that the method is being called?

Comment: Are you calling the Check method anywhere? It won't magically be called.

Comment: I am using Eclipse and i have checked that the method is being called.

Comment: Well i use this System.out.println("Starting"); and it dos not outprint it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unfortunately, I don’t know what the problem was. I reinstalled eclipse and it works now, thanks for your help if you took the time to drop by a possibility to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ouput to console won't show up if you start your program using `javaw`. It should work when started using `java`.

Let me guess: You start your program by double-clicking on the executable jar file? Then most probably that is configured to invoke `javaw`.

Comment: I started the game by debugging the program I have checked and I am using java. This usually works for me I am quite frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the application in a shell of your SO (cmd, sh, bash, ...) via java command. Ex:

```
javac myprogram.java
java myprogram
```

You'll have the output redirected to the same terminal. However, if you are using an IDE (eclipse, netbeans, etc) the output of the application will be redirected to the console of your development environment. I guess this is your case. Look for a windows called Console or similar.

Comment: I am using Eclipse but the output does not appear in that console.

Comment: Probably you are NOT executing the program you think you are running. Instead of pressing the debug button, which will be associated to the last program run, right-click on your file and select Run as an Application.